# Training Keras neural network with sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to train a neural network with [Keras](https://keras.io/).
My training set is comprised of millions of sparse vectors.

In order to perform the training, I use the model.fit() function:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, ...)
```

However, fit() operates on dense data. Therefore, in order to make it work - before feeding the network with the vectors - I transform them to dense vectors.

The problem is that after the transformation the data becomes too big and doesn't fit in the RAM anymore.

I know that I can use a `batch_generator` in order to feed the network in chunks of data. However, when I do that, I get results (on the test set)  that are worse than running without the `batch_generator` on only **part** of the data (so it does fit the RAM).

My question is: Is there a way to train a Keras neural network with sparse vectors, without transforming them to dense ones?

Comment: Fitting via a generator should yield the same results as fitting directly on the x/y arrays. Maybe what you perceive as better results is actually a case of overfitting (on the small subset of the data).

Comment: I use another set for testing and it is quite big. Why would an overfit perform better on the test set? It doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Your post didn't make it clear whether you meant the performance on the train or on a test set. Aside, `fit()` by default shuffles your data, make sure that your generator does that too at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Lasagne instead of Keras you can look at [this Multilayer Perceptron class](https://github.com/afshinrahimi/sparsemultilayerperceptron) which is very configurable and easy to read.

supports both dense and sparse matrices

supports drop-out and hidden layer

Supports complete probability distribution instead of one-hot labels so supports multilabel training.

Supports scikit-learn like API (fit, predict, accuracy, etc.)

Is very easy to configure and modify